# Is there a way to add back a small subset of media files to a CommCare mobile app without reinstalling?

Tags: commcare

Some users' CommCare app is showing that some media files are missing (instead of an image there is a "jpg is missing" message). These files are on CommCareHQ so it seems like they were just deleted from the phones. Is there an easy way to just reinstall the specific multimedia files (or all of the multimedia) without reinstalling the entire app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to install multimedia that does not involve reinstalling the application, though it will take a few steps. First, you will need a zip file containing all of the multimedia from the application. You can get this by proceeding to the Multimedia Reference Checker for the application on CommCareHQ and selecting Download Zip.

Next you will need to transfer the zip file onto the device. You can transfer it to any location on the device, though I would recommend a simple spot like the Downloads folder.

Once you have placed the zip file on the device with missing multimedia, login to the application. Select the Menu option from the home screen (on most devices, 3 dots in top right of screen). Select 'Advanced,' followed by 'Validate Multimedia.'

If there is missing multimedia, you will be brought to a screen that states what files are missing (If all media is there, you will receive a message stating all media validated and will be returned to the home screen). Select the Menu option again and note the option 'Install Multimedia' - select this. On the next screen, the path to the Zip file you transferred to the device should appear automatically. Select Install Multimedia and you should be good to go.

If the file path does not appear automatically, you will need to select the file image and find the zip file on the device before selecting Install Multimedia.